# How can I detect outlier depend on its neighbors with null values. (python, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering, outliers

How can I detect outliers depend on its neighbors.

I try to detect lane's on road, but because of road signs and other things, there is null values(-1) and noises.
For null values I will just bridging with this method.

```
def bridging(ar: np.ndarray):
    v_start = 0
    temp = 0
    latch = False
    for e, v in enumerate(ar):
        if not latch:
            if v == -1:   # enter -1 values
                latch = True
                v_start = e
                temp = ar[e-1]
        if latch:
            if v != -1:
                latch = False
                v_length = e - v_start + 2
                fill_values = np.linspace(temp, v, v_length)
                ar[v_start:e] = fill_values[1:-1]
    return ar
```

but before this method applied I have to detect and delete outliers depend on its neighbors.

I tried to use Savitzky Golay Filtering https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SavitzkyGolay.html but this can't accept null values.

for rough example bold font should be detected as outliers ([**184**,  -1,  -1,  -1, **756**, 430, 473, 567, 618, 589, 585, 464, 467,
**184**,  -1, 642,  -1, 389, 387,  -1, 589, 602, 728, 597, 568, 620,
610, 548, 424,  -1,  -1, 301,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1, 637], [  -1,   -1, 3686,   -1, 3740, 3653,   -1, 3656, 3633,   -1,   -1,
3421, 3389, 3560,   -1,   -1,   -1, 3340, 3313,   -1, 3418, 3566,
3643, 3751, 3580, 3686, 3683, 3625, 3515, 3467,   -1, 3431,   -1,
-1,   -1,   -1,   -1]

Comment: Can you explain what makes each of the bold items an outlier?  That would make it clearer what role you want the gaps to play relative to identifying outliers.  (The code snippet on bridging seems to be mostly a red herring, not very relevant to outliers as such.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace null with 0
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html
and then perform  Savitzky Golay Filtering.
Or you may remove null just for calculations https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html, perform filtering and add nulls at the end.

Comment: the reason that I leave null values but not delete it is because it does matter space between values(the further null values the greater the outlier margin is).

Comment: Ok, so why can't you replace it with non-nans that would be acceptable for filters?

Comment: If I replace null to specific value like 0 than will it not be affect the output values?